# Parametrization of an ellipse around a point

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I´m looking for a parametrization around a point $p=(p_1,p_2)$ on an ellipse. More precisely:

Let $E=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1 \}$ and $p=(p_1,p_2)\in E$. Find a parametrization $w:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to \mathbb{R^2}$ such that $w\in C^1$, $w(0)=p$  and  $w'(0)\neq (0,0)$ are valid.

I have found some parametrizations, but these one don´t lie on $E$.

Answer (score 1):

$E$ can be parameterized as 
$x(\theta) =a\cos(\theta)$ and $y(\theta)=b\sin(\theta)$

For some $\theta_0 \in C^1$, $(p_1, p_2) = (x(\theta_0), y(\theta_0))$

Then you could define $$W(t) = (a\cos(t-\theta_0), b\sin(t-\theta_0))$$